# why tab key is not moving focus to the next text field

Tags: jquery

I have got two Fields namely  Mobile Number and Password

When the focus is on  Mobile Number Text field and when the user presses **Tab** key the focus is not moving to the Password  field ??

This is my HTML page

```
<div class="createAccountWrap">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <label class="fieldLabel">Mobile Number</label>
      <div class="insideInput"><input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" id="vmobilenum" name="vmobilenum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required><a href="#" class=""></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <label class="fieldLabel">Password</label>
      <div class="insideInput"><input type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" id="vpwdcode" name="vpwdcode" onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)" required><a href="#" class=""></a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Could you please tell me why its not working ??

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/4371/

Comment: Because there's an `<a>` element right after the field?

Comment: Have a look at this, set the index https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need those **empty anchors** than use the **`tabindex` attribute** on your `input`elements

```
<input tabindex="1" ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/4372/

Otherwise remove the empty anchors. 
`a` elements are focusable elements too.

Answer (score 0):

try this using  "tabindex"

```
<div class="createAccountWrap">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <label class="fieldLabel">Mobile Number</label>
      <div class="insideInput"><input tabindex="1" type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" id="vmobilenum" name="vmobilenum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required><a href="#" class=""></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <label class="fieldLabel">Password</label>
      <div class="insideInput"><input tabindex="2" type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" id="vpwdcode" name="vpwdcode" onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)" required><a href="#" class=""></a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```